# How to create an object with references to variables owned by constructor?

Tags: rust

Here is a tentative socket constructor:

```rust
use std::net::TcpStream;

use rustls::{ClientConnection, RootCertStore, Stream};

pub struct TlsSocket<'a> {
    tls_instance: Stream<'a, ClientConnection, TcpStream>,
}

impl<'a> TlsSocket<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let root_store = RootCertStore::from_iter(webpki_roots::TLS_SERVER_ROOTS.iter().cloned());
        let mut config = rustls::ClientConfig::builder()
            .with_root_certificates(root_store)
            .with_no_client_auth();

        // Allow using SSLKEYLOGFILE.
        config.key_log = Arc::new(rustls::KeyLogFile::new());

        let server_name = "my_site.net".try_into().unwrap();
        let mut conn = rustls::ClientConnection::new(Arc::new(config), server_name).unwrap();
        let mut sock = TcpStream::connect("my_site.net:8000").unwrap();
        let tls = rustls::Stream::new(&mut conn, &mut sock);

        TlsSocket { tls_instance: tls }
    }
}
```

However, I get the error:

```
cannot return value referencing local variable `sock`
returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

I think I understand the error: at the end of the function `new`, `conn` and `sock` cannot be dangling. `new` should move them out, somehow.

I thought the lifetime annotation on Stream would let the compiler know that `conn` and `sock` must exist as long as the `tls` `rustls::Stream` exists...

```rust
pub struct Stream<'a, C, T>
where
    C: 'a + ?Sized,
    T: 'a + Read + Write + ?Sized, {
    pub conn: &mut C,
    pub sock: &mut T,
}
```

But that's not the case.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought the lifetime annotation on Stream would let the compiler know that `conn` and `sock` must exist as long as the tls `rustls::Stream` exists...

You are correct -- it does convey exactly that information to the compiler. However, the compiler will not automatically make it so! *You* are responsible for putting them somewhere that will outlive the `Stream`, and also where they won't be moved until the `Stream` ceases to exist. Because you haven't, the compiler gives you this error.

In other words, lifetimes give the compiler enough information to verify that what you're doing is correct, but it won't magically do extra things to satisfy the lifetime constraints.

`Stream` refers to an existing connection and socket, without taking ownership of them. Consider using [`StreamOwned`](https://docs.rs/rustls/latest/rustls/struct.StreamOwned.html) instead, which takes ownership of these values and therefore does not need to borrow anything.

Comment: I have heard this concept summed up as “lifetimes are descriptive, not prescriptive”, which is pretty short and sweet.

Comment: Oh, I appreciate the explanation! I sensed that I should move the ownership out, but did not know how to. StreamOwned is exactly what I needed, I'm imagining this pattern of providing an Owned and a Borrowed API must be very prevalent in Rust libraries - something I will look for next time. Thank you all!

Comment: @qnilab It's not always necessary to provide both versions because you can implement traits on references. For example, the built-in `std::io::Write` trait is implemented on `&mut T where T: Write`. So a type that contains a `Write`-implementing type could contain an owned _or_ a borrowed value.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought the lifetime annotation on Stream would let the compiler
> know that conn and sock must exist as long as the tls rustls::Stream
> exists...

This is right. The error arises because your `new` function is returning a TlsSocket object, which holds a reference to the internal `tls` field. which in turn holds references to `conn` and `sock` through the `Stream` instance. However, conn and sock are local variables declared within the new function and get deallocated when the function exits. This creates a dangling reference resulting in the error you are seeing.

One option to fix this problem is to make `conn` and `sock` new owners of the ClientConnection and TcpStream instances. To do that,

just declare `conn` and `sock` with `let` alone, drop `mut` and then move them directly into your `new` function instead of using their references:

```
    let conn = rustls::ClientConnection::new(Arc::new(config), server_name).unwrap();
    let sock = TcpStream::connect("qbalin.dynu.net:8000").unwrap();
    let tls = rustls::StreamOwned::new(conn, sock);
```

Comment: This will not compile. `rustls::Stream::new()` takes mutable references.

Comment: You are right. Then the Op can use `StreamOwned` as you have already mentioned in your answer. Just edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! ‍♂️ This was helpful for my understanding of the language!